# connect to Bluetooth device after discovery bluetooth in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

From the bluetooth chat sample, it shows

The sample demonstrates the following, using the Bluetooth API:

1. Setting up Bluetooth
   I had done
2. Scanning for other Bluetooth devices
   I had discoveries device on my listview
3. Querying the local Bluetooth adapter for paired Bluetooth devices
   How can I put discovery device into pair device. Generally I need to select one of list device,     then I press the device, write pin code in API to send the code. Before I collect discovery device into pair device, which API codes I need to do?
4. Establishing RFCOMM channels/sockets
   from pair devices, I
5. Connecting to a remote device
6. Transferring data over Bluetooth
   How to do? thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please explain with some code and more details with logs ?

Comment: from Android phone, I turn to Bluetooth item, then I choose discovery, I find some device on the list. Then I choose first device (that is not pair device). It will let me to connect or ask the pin code. But My bluetooth code had implemented to get all discovery device (that is unpair devices). How to use Bluetooth API to let discovery device into pair device, so I can play music from phone into bluetooth device.